# How do I read Passport.js user info on client side?

Tags: express, angular, oauth, passport.js

My app is using Angular2 for the front-end, served by a separate (cross domain) backend server running express and using passport.js for Google Oauth authentication.

When a user is authenticated by the server using Passport (through google oauth), their user data is loaded from the database and included in the credentials, which is used to determine which backend API routes they are authorized to use. (It's based off this tutorial on scotch.io that I'm sure everyone has seen: https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local )

I want to access this user object in my front-end as well to enable route-guards that depend on a user's access level (defined in their user object on the server).

From this question it seems the data is sent via a JWT and is readable on the front-end, just not changeable, which is fine: https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/4ud0ac/ng2_secure_connection_front_to_back/

How do I access and read that token on the client?  All I can find is the 'connect.sid' session cookie set by express. The payload of the cookie doesn't fit a standard JWT as it only has 2 sections, not 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably not using JWT but cookie-based sessions if you followed the tutorial. The cookie only contains a session ID which your server uses to identify the session from the session store, and using this information you probably dig up something from the database in `deserializeUser`. That is then available to you in `req.user` in the backend.

You could of course add the user data to the response of every request but if you really are using cookie-based sessions sending the user object with every response likely makes little sense. You could eg. just add a route that will return the relevant parts of `req.user`:

```
app.get('/users', function(req, res) {
  res.json({ username : req.user.username });
);
```

Comment: I think I get it now. 

Express is setting a unique id (session) on the client as a cookie.  When the client sends credentials along with a request, that cookie's string is sent and then their user details are added into the req object on the server where I can work with them. The user details are not actually transferred off the server back to the client at any point.

So I misunderstood completely how it worked originally.  I need to go and check how to implement Passport.js with JWTs instead.

Thanks, exactly what I needed!